How to save VNDocumentCameraViewController scanned pages to Swift Data model?
I have defined a struct to open the VNDocumentCameraViewController in a SwiftUI environment:
struct DocumentCameraView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var firstScanned: Data
    @Binding var lastScanned: Data?

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> VNDocumentCameraViewController {
        let documentCameraViewController = VNDocumentCameraViewController()
        documentCameraViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
        return documentCameraViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: VNDocumentCameraViewController, context: Context) {}

    class Coordinator: NSObject, VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate {
        var parent: DocumentCameraView

        init(_ parent: DocumentCameraView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func documentCameraViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController) {
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            // Handle the error appropriately
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFinishWith scan: VNDocumentCameraScan) {
            // Handle the scanned document
            let first = scan.imageOfPage(at: 0).pngData()
            let last = scan.imageOfPage(at: 1).pngData()
                
            parent.firstScanned = first!
            parent.lastScanned = last

            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

I have the following Swift Data model:
@Model
class BusinessCard {
    var name: String
    var address: String
    var phoneNumber: String
    var email: String
    var isFavourite: Bool
    var dateCreated: Date
    
    @Attribute(.externalStorage)
    var frontImage: Data?
    
    @Attribute(.externalStorage)
    var backImage: Data?
}

At this moment I'm settings the value of firstScanned and LastScanned as Binding variables to pass them between views but it's really slow and heavy on the phone resources.
I also have the following function:
func addBusinessCard () {
        let frontImageData: Data = self.firstScanned
        let backImageData: Data? = self.lastScanned
        let businessCard = BusinessCard(frontImage: frontImageData, backImage: backImageData)
        modelContext.insert(businessCard)
        path = [businessCard]
}

that gets called inside the following view that contains the list of business cards present in the Model:
struct FolioView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    
    @Query var businessCards: [BusinessCard]
    
    @State var firstScanned: Data = (UIImage("biscard_front_test")?.pgnData())!
    @State var lastScanned: Data?

    @State private var showScanSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var path = [BusinessCard]()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            List {
                ForEach(businessCards, id: \.id) { businessCard in
                    NavigationLink(value: businessCard) {
                        BizCardListItem(frontImg: businessCard.frontImage, name: businessCard.name, dateCreated: businessCard.dateCreated, isFavourite: businessCard.isFavourite)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteBusinessCard)
            }
            .listRowSpacing(10)
            .navigationTitle("Business Cards")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button { showScanSheet.toggle() } label: { Text("Scan") }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: BusinessCard.self, destination: BizCardDetailsView.init)
            .onChange(of: firstScanned) { oldValue, newValue in
                addBusinessCard()
            }
           　.sheet(isPresented: $showScanSheet) {
　　　　　　　　　　DocumentCameraView(firstScanned: $firstScanned, lastScanned: $lastScanned)
        　　　　　　　　.ignoresSafeArea()
            　　　　　.presentationDetents([.medium])
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always), prompt: "Search")
    }
    
    func addBusinessCard () {
        let frontImageData: Data = self.firstScanned
        let backImageData: Data? = self.lastScanned
        let businessCard = BusinessCard(frontImage: frontImageData, backImage: backImageData)
        modelContext.insert(businessCard)
        path = [businessCard]
    }
}

Is there a better way to pass Scanned images as Data from the VNDocumentCameraViewController to a view and then saving it inside of a SwiftData model?

Looking at your code, you don’t seem to be using the bindings in your DocumentCameraView.
Also not clear why you are not using firstScanned and lastScanned directly in your func addBusinessCard .
Where do you declare your @State private var firstScanned ... and lastScanned?

@workingdogsupportUkraine I corrected the code, now everything is as minal and reproducible as possible. Thanks for pointing it out.

So you are saying everthing works but it is ...slow and heavy on the phone resources
and you are looking for a better way.

@workingdogsupportUkraine yes, that's what I say at the end of the question. The debug navigator tool in Xcode is showing peaks of over 90% in the CPU section. I've tried it both in the simulator and on my real phone and the both slow down for easy task like typing inside a text field. So yeah I'm looking for the best alternative if possible.
